# How to use a trained model on new inputs?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have created a CNN model that can be used to differentiate DOGS and CATS. During the training process my model was showing an training accuracy of 99% and testing accuracy of 81% by the end of 4/25 epoch. 
Is this normal? or is there any problem that might occur after completion of all the epoch's?

So I need to use this CNN model to my new inputs that do not belong to my training of test set. How do I use my model to predict some new photos?

I have not used `classifier.save( )`, so after the training can I just use that command so that model gets saved? or do I have to recompile everything with `clssifier.save()` at the end?

```
# Part 1 - Building the CNN

# Importing the Keras libraries and packages
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dense

# Initialising the CNN
classifier = Sequential()

# Step 1 - Convolution
classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape = (64, 64, 3), activation = 'relu'))

# Step 2 - Pooling
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

# Adding a second convolutional layer
classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

# Step 3 - Flattening
classifier.add(Flatten())

# Step 4 - Full connection
classifier.add(Dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(units = 1, activation = 'sigmoid'))

# Compiling the CNN
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

# Part 2 - Fitting the CNN to the images

from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                                   shear_range = 0.2,
                                   zoom_range = 0.2,
                                   horizontal_flip = True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('dataset/training_set',
                                                 target_size = (64, 64),
                                                 batch_size = 32,
                                                 class_mode = 'binary')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('dataset/test_set',
                                            target_size = (64, 64),
                                            batch_size = 32,
                                            class_mode = 'binary')

classifier.fit_generator(training_set,
                         steps_per_epoch = 8000,
                         epochs = 25,
                         validation_data = test_set,
                         validation_steps = 2000)
```

Answer (score 0):

The model has a `save` method that exports the architecture and training configuration of the model to a file which can be later extracted and used. The documentation for the same can be found [here](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-save-a-keras-model).

After importing the model, you can use the model on any data sets that you want to. About the accuracy of the model, it is possible to achieve the same. There is still a huge difference between the train and test accuracy so at the moment it is over-fitting the data. Also, try to randomize the data and train using them to make sure it is not an exceptional case.